# Help with a Lebesgue integration problem

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $(X,m,\mu)$ be a Lebesgue measure space and $f:(X,m)\to[0,\infty]$ be a Lebesgue measurable function such that $\int_X f d\mu=3$. For each $n\in N$ consider the function $g_n:(X,m)\to[0,\infty)$ given by $$g_n(x)=n\ln(1+\frac{f(x)}{n})$$ Show that $g_n$ is a measurable function for each $n\in N$ and that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Xg_nd\mu=3$

The first half of the problem looks fine. $\forall N$, $1+\frac{f(x)}{n}$ is measurable, $\ln(x)$ is continuous on $(0,+\infty)$, so $\ln(1+\frac{f(x)}{n})$ is measurable.

But I got a problem with the second half. Since $g_n \ge 0$ and is increasing with $n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}g_n(x)=e^{f(x)}$, then by monotone convergence theorem we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_Xg_nd\mu=\int_Xe^{f(x)}d\mu$. But it seems not possible that $\int_Xe^{f(x)}d\mu=3$. Where am I going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You made an error in the computation of your limit of $g_n$.

Comment: Stupid me!!!!!!!!!!!! I overlooked $\ln$ for the limit

Comment: Stupid I wouldn't say. Call it inattentive!